# gnuplot-iostream won't compile

Tags: c++, boost, gnuplot

I was wondering if someone could help me with this.

I've retrieved the source code for the gnuplot-iostream interface from http://www.stahlke.org/dan/gnuplot-iostream/. However, when I attempt to compile the code using the command:

```
]$ cmake .; make
```

I get the following compiler error

```
/.../gnuplot-iostream.h: In constructor ‘Gnuplot::Gnuplot(const std::string&)’:
/.../gnuplot-iostream.h:427: error: ‘never_close_handle’ is not a member of ‘boost::iostreams’
```

I'm using Scientific Linux 6.2 (kernal 2.6.32-220.23.1.el6.x86_64), g++ 4.4.6, and have boost libraries installed (/usr/include/boost/iostreams/ exists).

Any assistance would be very much appreciated.

D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`enum file_descriptor_flags` was added in `boost::iostreams` only in 1.44.0.

```
enum file_descriptor_flags
{
    never_close_handle = 0,
    close_handle = 3
};
```

Comment: Yep, that's it! The version of boost installed on our system is 1.41. Will have to get sys admin onto this :( Cheers for your help ForEveR

Answer (score 2):

So, the solution is simply update the boost library (thanks ForEveR).

If however, like me, you do not have the access to update the libraries on your system you should note that I was able to force compilation and obtain basic functionality by simply replacing the two occurrences of boost::iostreams::never_close_handle in the gnuplot-iostream.h file with 0.